# Use cases for p-adic numbers in probability and statistics?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, p-adic

I saw [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.13877.pdf) and wondered if there are more applications of p-adics in stats and probability that do not zoom in on deep boltzman machines... something more general.

Further, non-Kolmogorov interpretations of probability were discussed in [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=40e58b7772e054b6b8acf1d284edf50274cc12c5).

I am just putting out feelers to get a sense of the interesting intersection of probability/stats and p-adics.

Comment: I'm amazed there are *any* potential applications of p-adic numbers in statistics!  The crux of the matter seems to be how the topology of inverse limits can model connections among neurons.